# Do builtin libraries not need to be specified to `javac` but to `java`?

Tags: java

I read [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46625798/how-to-use-classpath-options-of-javac-and-java?noredirect=1#comment80202490_46625798) which says that

> If you're just compiling some java code that uses the built-in libraries, you won't need to specify a classpath at all. You will need to specify the classpath when running the program.

I feel it is asymmetric that we don't need to specify builtin libraries used in a program   to `javac` when  compling the program, but need to do so to `java` when running the compiled program.

Is my understanding of the comment correct? If yes, why is the asymmetry? Could you give some examples?

Thanks.

Comment: By built-in libraries that comment is referring to the Java standard libraries. You wouldn't need to specify them for `java`. Any external dependency/library must be included in the `classpath` parameter for both `java` and `javac`.

Comment: Thanks. do you mean I don't need to specify standard libraries to both `javac` and `java`?

Comment: Indeed, and by standard library, I mean everything that is included in this documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/

Comment: "Nope" means "You don't mean ..." or "I don't need to"? For any library, standard or not, is it correct that either it is specified to both `javac` and `java` or to neither of them when compiling and running a program that uses the library?

Comment: My bad, poor choice of wording. You do not need to include the standard library inthe classpath for either `java` or `javac` commands.

Comment: When you are not using any external libraries (that are not included in the JSE, refer to the documentation link I posted above), you do not need to include any libraries in your `classpath` for both `java` and `javac` commands. As soon as you are using an external library, you will have to include that external library in your `classpath` parameter for both the `java` and the `javac` command.

Comment: Thanks. Do `java` and `javac` use the same ways to search for an external package? Ways such as option `-classpath`, environment variable `CLASSPATH`, or default paths?

Comment: Yes.  They search the same way.

Comment: The comment you linked to is unclear.  But you should do what the comments on that question and this one say:  READ THE DOCUMENTATION.  It is all explained there ... clearly, and in detail.